# AngularJS UI-Router: Matching state with $state.includes in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS (1.5.1) component.  This component appears throughout my app.

I need to do something in this component's template based on the currently active URL.

For example, when the app is displaying `#/web/foundation/color` or any other state with `web` in the url, I need to set a class with ng-class. So I need to return `true` if the url has a given href.

I was trying to use `ng-class="{'active' : $state.includes('web')}"`

The state associated with that url is

```
$stateProvider.state('color', {
  url: '/web/foundation/color'}
});
```

I have several others in the `web` section, set up similarly, such as

```
$stateProvider.state('buttons', {
  url: '/web/foundation/buttons'}
});
```

So `web` is part of the URL but not the state name.

The component itself is

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app').component('pbDsLeftnav', {
    bindings: {},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'core/directives/pb-ds-leftnav.component.html',
    controller: function ($log, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
      var _this = this;

      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

      console.log($state.includes('web'));
    }
  });
})();
```

I have tried various versions of `'web'`, `**.web.**` to no avail. It always logs `false`.  How do I match a part of the state's url?

Comment: Got it.  But `console.log($state.href($state));` just errors out.

Comment: This logs as `null` now:  `console.log($state.href($state.current));`

Comment: If I do `console.log($state.get($state.current));` I get `{name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}`